# Packed struct in C different memory layout from C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct in a C program, which, when I dump its content top stdout, has all uninitialized fields set to 0 (see `usb_interface_descriptor` here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/usb/ch9.h#L351).

```
struct {
    struct usb_interface_descriptor intf;
    //more members, but ignored here
} __attribute__((packed)) fs_descs = {
    intf.bLength = sizeof fs_descs.intf,
    intf.bDescriptorType = USB_DT_INTERFACE,
    intf.bNumEndpoints = 2,
    intf.bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC,
    intf.iInterface = 1,
};
```

Now in C++ I would expect the memory layout of the struct that you can see below to be the same but the fileds that are not initialized, are not zero but seem to have random values like `0xFFFFFFFB`.
How can I make sure that the struct is equal to the one in the C code with the designated initializers?
Thanks!

```
struct stDescriptorBody {
    usb_interface_descriptor intf;
    stDescriptorBody(){
    }
}__attribute__((packed)); 

struct stDescriptor {
    //more members
    stDescriptorBody            fs_descs;

    stDescriptor(){
        fs_descs.intf.bLength = sizeof (fs_descs.intf);
        fs_descs.intf.bDescriptorType = USB_DT_INTERFACE;   
        // not initialized __u8 .bInterfaceNumber;
        // not initialized __u8 .bAlternateSetting;
        fs_descs.intf.bNumEndpoints = 2;
        fs_descs.intf.bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC; 
        // not initialized __u8  .bInterfaceSubClass;
        // not initialized __u8  .bInterfaceProtocol;
        fs_descs.intf.iInterface = 1;
    }
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Comment: Uninitialized fields are ... uninitialized. Some compiler (in some configuration) may initialize memory with some pattern (as 0, 0xFF, 0x0BADF00D, ...). If you want a given value, initialize these fields yourself (`memset` as it is plain C struct ?).

Comment: How is initialization related to layout? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** How can I make sure that the struct is equal to the one in the C code with the designated initializers?

**A:**  One way to do this is to write a wrapper program in C, populating each field with an identifiable (unique) value, and writing the values to a file. The write a corresponding wrapper program in C++, and compare the contents of the two resulting files.  If they're identical, so are the memory layouts, assuming you use a write function which just writes a block of memory.

If your concern is about how structures are initialized, any fields you need initialized, you'll need to initialize in your code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-initialize the POD struct instead of not-initializing it.

That is, replace:

```
stDescriptorBody(){
}
```

with:

```
stDescriptorBody() : intf() {
}
```